# Magento 2.3 Create Custom Module

Tags: magento2.3

I am trying to get some code onto the success page for a Magento store. I know that it needs to be done through a custom module but I can't even seem to get a base module to register though. I have been through countless tutorials that all explain the same thing and stating that it is extremely easy but it does not seem to be so. I have tried inside `app/code` (note this folder didn't even exist, I had to create it), I have also tried in `Vendor`. I created a base module with the two required files:

VendorName/MyModule/registration.php:

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'VendorName_MyModule',
__DIR__
);
```

VendorName/MyModule/etc/module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="VendorName_MyModule" setup_version="0.0.1">
</config>
```

Then ran these commands:
`php bin/magento module:enable VendorName_MyModule`
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

I was then told that I can run this command to verify it worked:
`grep VendorName app/etc/config.php`

but this is not returning anything indicating it is not working.

Any assistance on this would be appreciated. It is mind boggling how difficult this is, when all I am trying to do is add a few lines of code to one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link [Create a New Module](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)

Comment: I have followed this exact tutorial and when I got to the part of checking that the module registered, it appeared to not have been. This article gives no advice for if this was not to work.